# Dynamically rendering react components

Tags: facebook, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I'm having a hell of a time understanding this bug.

I've read this, and it seems like the solution is there but I'm drawing a blank on how to implement this correctly:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

I am trying to render components based on classNames of clicked elements. The classNames match to component names. When I click an element it calls a function that sets the state of my app to that elements className. I then render the component based on the new state.

When testing, if I place the component directly into my app (not rendering the component name dynamically), it works just fine. But when i render the component name dynamically react thinks it's a built-in DOM element and doesn't render properly at all.

In this image you can see both components, rendered next to each other:

[both components, first directly added, and the second with the name rendered dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gVG5.png)

here is my app component code that is rendering everything:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import '../css/App.css';
import menus from '../menus';
import MainNav from './MainNav';
import Products from './Products';
import Demos from './Demos';
import Industry from './Industry';
import Customers from './Customers';
import Trials from './Trials';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Newsroom from './Newsroom';
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';



class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.chooseComponent = this.chooseComponent.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            allMenus: menus,
            componentMenu: menus,
            //sets initial component to load, changes on each click to the clicked component
            clickedComponent: Home

        };
    }  

    chooseComponent(event) {
            //save the classname of the menu i click
            var clickedComp = event.target.className;
            //saves a reference to a json object for later use
            var menu = menus[clickedComp];
            //adds those two vars to the state
            this.setState({
                componentMenu: menu,
                clickedComponent: clickedComp
            }); 
    }

    render() {
        //saves a var for rendering the currently clicked component
        var ActiveComponent = this.state.clickedComponent;
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <MainNav choose={this.chooseComponent}/>
        //renders the components directly without issue
        <Products menuData={this.state.componentMenu} />
        //renders the component dynamically with problems
        <ActiveComponent menuData={this.state.componentMenu} />
      </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

here is and example of one of my component being rendered in the App that's giving problems:

```
import React from 'react';
import products from '../products';
import ProductsMenu from './ProductsMenu';
import Platform from './Platform';
import Applications from './Applications';
import ExMachina from './ExMachina';
import ProductsHome from './ProductsHome';
import Submenu from './Submenu';
import menus from '../menus';



class Products extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.showContent=this.showContent.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            productsOverview: products,
            content: <ProductsHome />
        }
    }

    render(props) {

        return (
                <div className="content">
                    {this.state.content}   
                </div>

             );
    }
}
export default Products;
```

Comment: So what's the actual issue that happens when you render it dynamically? You say "doesn't render properly at all" do you mean instead of the Products component being INSIDE the Main component, it's rendered next to it?

Comment: the Products component doesn't have any of the content it's supposed to contain when rendered dynamically. in the image i posted, the Products component that's rendered correctly creates it's own closing tag and has other child components that render inside it. the dynamic one has none of that, and shows as a grey element - the same as a normal built-in DOM node - when viewing via the React Developer tools. hope that makes sense

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your bug. I made a small fiddle of dynamically rendering a component that's stored in the state and it works fine, lemme know what the difference is between that and yours: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83045/

Comment: Ultimately components shouldn't really be stored in the state, the state should be minimal. It should just contain the data needed to render the components, not the entire component itself.

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444 for the advice and at least trying to figure it out. I'm guessing it's something to do with how I have things nested, and probably something just really stupid/obvious in the end. I had a switch statement that was working fine before, but I thought I could do it with less code this way :/ I'm going to try to come up with a smarter way to do this without storing those components in the state. Maybe go back to that switch statement! :)

Comment: Yeah I often use switch statements and conditional rendering and such. Best of luck!